# How to increase RStudio editor size?

Tags: rstudio

In Eclipse, I am able to do Ctrl+M while I am typing in the editor to full-screen the editor and temporarily hide all the side-windows. Is there a way to achieve this in RStudio? The code editor portion of the window is very small and yet I don't feel like manually fiddling with the mouse to resize my console/plots/workspace windows.

The view menu doesn't offer much else than zooming in/out.

Comment: Are your scripts wider than 80 characters (google style guide)? If they aren't, I don't really see the point of a fullscreen. But I keep my editor on the left, console on the right, and the other two minimized when editing; fullscreen on a mbp, hiding all toolbars, etc. Anyway, I don't have an answer to your question, but my guess would be no.

Comment: I try to abide to the 80-char width rule. The main reasons I sometimes want a full-screen editor: (1) focus - hide everything else, but the code; (2) bigger text - especially when I'm on a laptop, I sometimes want to zoom into the text (Ctrl +) and in such occasions some extra width gives me the space to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

You can make the editor fill up the entire rstudio window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. Also to restore.

To move between the panes, the shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + number.
1 - source
2 - console

Adding shift to the shortcut makes that pane fill up the spaces.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I've found [is to use a "source window"](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/207126217-Using-Source-Windows), i.e. pop out the editor into a separate window temporarily:

[image]

This window can then be expanded to fill the whole screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Only way I know how is to click on the right hand side of the title bar of the source code section where it has 2 windows symbols. The right-most one expands the code window to the entire left hand side.

Instructions and documentation below from the R studio manual: 
http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/console

Comment: Thanks. I already knew about that one, though. I was hoping to get it to cover the whole screen - that way I can zoom into the text a bit to rest my eyes now and then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Linux, you can install RStudio Server, just for use on the same computer. It's almost exactly like the regular RStudio, but inside a browser. I prefer it because I can full screen, and can use the browser's Find in the console.