# R Notebook in fullscreen mode

Tags: rstudio, fullscreen

I'm trying to enlarge the window of a R notebook, but it seems that the maximum size is half of the sceen. Is it possible to write in a R notebook in fullscreen mode?

---

EDIT: I'm referring to the window on the left side.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the rendered HTML output or about the size of the *window* that RStudio shows the notebook in?

Comment: Hello @KonradRudolph I'm talking about the size of the window

Comment: Try `CTRL+SHIFT+1` ? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/21665284/680068

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase RStudio editor size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21665284/how-to-increase-rstudio-editor-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some css to your Rmd-file to overwrite the width constrained of R Notebook preview:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

<style>
.main-container {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
</style>

This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code. 

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*.
```

You can make the source code window of RStudio editor full screen by clicking on View > Panes > Zoom Source

Comment: Hello @danloo thank you for your answer. I tried, but nothing happens

Comment: What is your header of your Rmd file? My answer is based on HTML. You need to insert the `<style>` tag to adjust the styling

Comment: I'm using RStudio window, not html

Comment: The pop-up window after clicking the Preview button? This is just a browser and the style will also apply there.

Comment: see the edit please

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I revised my answer